# Latex subsections inside figure - toc shows subsections

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I try to put a lot of these elements inside my thesis:

```
\subsection{Maschine}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=gray!10,text width=0.9\textwidth, draw, minimum height=1 cm] at (1,9)
{\begin{center}\textbf{Factory}\end{center}};
\node[fill=white,text width=0.9\textwidth, draw, minimum height=1 cm] at (1,8)
{String bestehend aus beliebig vielen Komponenten};
\node[fill=white,text width=0.9\textwidth, draw, minimum height=1 cm] at (1,7)
{\texttt{<Factory> Komponenten </Factory>}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\vspace{0.5cm}
Description
\end{figure}
```

I want to have them fixed. So I wrote a figure tag around the subsection.

Before this code I used the next line to prevent, that these subsections are shown in the table of content:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
```

But they are shown, because of the figure tag around the subsections.

Is there a way to prevent latex from putting them into the toc or keep the subsections together without the figure tag?